# Is there a way to make C++ take in an undefined number of strings from cin?

Tags: c++, string, user-interface, cin

I am trying to allow the user to input a decent number of words (around 10-20) and then parse the input, but using the code below will wait until the user has input a value for *every* string.

Is there a way to make C++ auto fill the remaining strings with the null character or something similar so the entry of a number of words less than the max won't cause a holdup?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string test1;
  std::string test2;
  std::string test3;
  std::cout << "Enter values\n:";
  std::cin >> test1 >> test2 >> test3;
  std::cout << "test1: " << test1 << " test2: " << test2 << " test3: " << test3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: use `getline` and put all the words into a single string.

Comment: Looks like a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) could be useful to you. If you presize it to, say, 20, `std::vector<std::string> myvec(20)` it will make 20 empty strings. You can then read into these empty strings with `cin` up to the maximum of 20. If you read in 15, fifteen are changed and the other five stay empty.

Comment: Typical usage of vector in a case like this is you don't presize it (but might `reserve` some storage) and then `push_back` the strings you read into it. `vector` will resize itself to handle all the strings you can give it until it runs your computer out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read (and store) and unknown number of whitespace separate strings, you need storage for each string. The most basic way to provide the storage in a flexible way that can be added to in an unlimited (up to your usable memory limit) is with a *vector of strings*. The string provides storage for each string and the vector container provides an easy way to collect any number of strings together.

Your vector-of-strings (`vs`) can be declared as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...
    std::vector<std::string>vs {};
```

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) provides the `.push_back()` member function to add an element (a `string` in this case) to the vector, e.g.

```
    std::vector<std::string>vs {};
    std::string s;

    while (std::cin >> s)
        vs.push_back(s);
```

Which simply reads string `s` until `EOF` is encountered, and each string read is added to the vector-of-strings using `vs.push_back(s);`.

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    std::vector<std::string>vs {};
    std::string s;

    while (std::cin >> s)  /* read each string into s */
        vs.push_back(s);   /* add s to vector of strings */

    for (auto& w : vs)     /* output each word using range-based loop */
        std::cout << w << "\n";

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has fleas" | ./bin/readcintostrings
my
dog
has
fleas
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop .Something like this

```
string s;
while (cin >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

or take a vector of strings and  make a while , Take inputs in while loop and push them into vector.

as you see it doesn't store. if you want to store. 
do

```
vector<string>text;
while(cin>>s){
   text.push_back(s);}
```

Comment: This fails to store the `string`s, and that's the hard part of this problem: Storing a variable number of items.

Comment: @user4581301 See now . I have modified it .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string testTemp;
  std::string brokenUp[20];
  int lastOne = 0;

  std::cout << "Enter values\n:";
  std::getline(std::cin, testTemp);

  for(int current = 0; !testTemp.empty() && testTemp.find(' ') != -1; current++)
  {
    brokenUp[current] = testTemp.substr(0, testTemp.find(' '));
    testTemp.erase(0, testTemp.find(' ') + 1);
    lastOne = current;
  }
  lastOne++;
  brokenUp[lastOne] = testTemp;

  //this next part is just a test
  for(int i = 0; i <= lastOne; i++)
  {
    std::cout << brokenUp[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

but you could use anything as the storage for the broken up strings (i.e. a list or a dynamic array).

Comment: Warning: `for(int i = 0; i <= lastOne; i++)` looks like an off by one bug. the range of the `i` will be 0 to (and including) `lastOne`for a total count of `lastOne` + 1 visited array elements. You won't see it in the output until you fill up the array because printing out an empty `string` doesn't do anything. But when you do fill up the array, printing out the non-existent 21 array element could do anything including look like the program works.